# What to search for multiple RTL words in a string?

Tags: regex, search, right-to-left

How do I search and find three words in an Arabic text where order of these words is not important? All these three words have to exist in the sentence with no particular order. [I am using RegexBuddy on Win 7 Pro. and there are thousands of text files in a folder.]

Here is suppose a text:

```
ما أهدى مسلم لأخيه هدية أفضل من كلمة حكمة يزيده الله بها هدى أو يرده بها عن أذى
```

I want to search the words `كلمة` **and** `أفضل` **and** `أذى`  .

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then you can search for them just as you would search for words in any other language. Arabic's being written right-to-left doesn't influence regular expression look up.

Comment: Would you care to give me the exact code to find all wanted words in a sentence so to run it on RegexBuyddy?

Comment: Does it have to be one regex? If yes, why?
What did you try already?

Comment: No it doesn't have to be regex. Any method that works on Windows 7 Pro 64 bit would be just fine. Keep in mind I need a content search for all three words found in just one file among thousands.

Comment: I must be missing something, because what you describe is a very simple string search that doesn't require any special syntax.